# Make Div fit full window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm setting up a site at unclick and I want the slider images in the first section to fit the full window.

Can I do this just with CSS or will I need javascript as well?

The div holding the slider images has the id `#section1` and it's this section that needs to fit the window.

Any help would be immense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this ([use viewport units](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)):

**CSS**

```
#section1, .et_pb_slider .et_pb_slide {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

> Beware, if you leave the mouse hover the images, the slide stops...You
>   gonna have a full image in a full screen , so the mouse inevitable
>   goes hover full screen...just a tip.

Comment: Luis you are a legend!! How do I recommend or score you for your rating?

Comment: Thanks for the tip as well. Now I know about the vh property I might have a single background Image with a button in the first section to link to my portfolio when I've uploaded it.  Thanks again Luis.

Comment: @PaulKnight you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

This CSS would make a div fill the full browser window:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
```

Comment: That didn't work i'm afraid.